# Mathematical modeling of population using logistic growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am currently preparing for my finals and I came across one problem which I couldn't solve. I've been struggling with this for a few days.

---

> The farmer owns $50$ animals and land that can feed $1000$ animals. The natural increase for a small number of animals is at the annual level of $p = 1$. To provide incentives, the state offers a free lease of land in the same area for a period of $5$ years. At which point in time should the farmer start using additional land to:
>
> 1. Have the largest number of animals after $10$ years?
> 2. Have the highest average number of animals in $10$ years?
>
> The use of numerical methods is allowed.

---

I am familiar with logistic growth (Verhulst's model), but I don't know how to start. Any help would be much appreciated. Sorry if my English was bad.

Comment: Some context is needed here. Finals of what? What is $p$? Also, one question mentions an average. So, are we supposed to make stochastic model?

Comment: @KBS Finals of introduction to mathematical modeling. $p$ is the old population plus the number of births minus the number of deaths during the time period. You are not supposed to make a stochastic model, just one using differential equations.

Comment: Then, how is the average computed?